# How to load Lottie animation and pause on given Frame number in Lottie compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, lottie, android-lottie

I am using Lottie animation but if user has turned off animation from accessibility settings then I just want to load animation with a given frame number.

In native(non compose) version I was using this convenient method  [LottieAnimationView.setFrame(int frame)](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/34aa06b8db75976f06b134b4fdcdb7dc26e48e07/lottie/src/main/java/com/airbnb/lottie/LottieAnimationView.java#L1073) which was working as expected.

Now we are migrating native screens to jetpack compose and I cant find a way to load a animation with a given frame number.

So just wanted to know how to achieve [LottieAnimationView.setFrame(int frame)](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/34aa06b8db75976f06b134b4fdcdb7dc26e48e07/lottie/src/main/java/com/airbnb/lottie/LottieAnimationView.java#L1073) effect in compose version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `LottieClipSpec`

Use `LottiesClipSpec` with `Frame` specs and specify argument as per your need. All params are optional for `Frame` specs.

```
...

LottieAnimation(
    composition = composition,
    clipSpec = LottieClipSpec.Frame(
        min = <Int>, 
        max = <Int>, 
        maxInclusive = <Bool>
    )
)

...
```

There are different ways to load the animation like Frame, Progress and Markers.

Just check this once
https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/lottie-compose/src/main/java/com/airbnb/lottie/compose/LottieClipSpec.kt

**The another approach is, Use `LottieAnimationView` inside composable `AndroidView` (Not preferable)**